# Why i can't run this jar with shell_exec?

Tags: java, php, jar, shell-exec

i have create the java class below. This class uses twitter4java api for java-twitter communication.

```
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;

import java.util.List;

public class SearchTweets {

    public static String API_Key = new String("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    public static String API_Secret = new String("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    public static String Access_Token = new String("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    public static String Access_Token_Secret = new String("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(API_Key, API_Secret);
        AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(Access_Token, Access_Token_Secret);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

        try {
            Query query = new Query("paok");
            QueryResult result;
            do {
                result = twitter.search(query);
                List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
                for (int i=0 ; i < tweets.size() ; i++)  {
                    Status s = tweets.get(i);
                    if (s.getPlace() != null) {
                        System.out.println("@" + s.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + s.getPlace().getName());                     
                    }
                }
            } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

I have create it in eclipse. Now i want run it on a web site with php. I use shell_exec. First i create a simple java class for testing and all running ok.

After i go run my SearchTweets class and i can't. I export my project in a jar from eclipse. But when go run it i take this from terminal

> itsoum@itsoum-Inspiron-3542:/opt/lampp/htdocs/tweet$ java -jar
>   ilias.jar Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   twitter4j/TwitterException    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)    at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)    at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   twitter4j.TwitterException    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 6 more

Any idea what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your program refers to external library (twitter4j), you would need to reference this external lib to run your program

You have two options:

- include all jar files from the lib directory into the manifest of your jar file (you can use relative paths there)
- Specify everything (including your jar) on the command line using -cp: 
  `java -cp ilias.jar:<path to twitter4j.jar>  SearchTweets.Main`

Comment: First of all i thanks you for answer. Can you tell the specific command line order for run my SearchTweets? I need many twitter4j jars. Must I re-compile from terminal or no?

Comment: you do not need to recompile - if you have many `jar` file you can include them all with `java -cp ilias.jar:lib/*.jar  SearchTweets.Main` assuming all your jar files are in the lib/ folder under your project structure

Comment: Also how see if i have include all jars files into the manifest? What exactly is manifest?

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class TwitterTest.Main
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxuSpi5N7V7fbFRqNW1lQmFOY0U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: to be short, [manifest.mf is a text file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) which contain information about the files packaged in a JAR file. if your specific lib refers to others jar files, you can indicate in it. If you're not so familiar with Jar and manifest file creation, you can stick with option 2

Comment: is your class TwitterTest or SearchTweets, in your question you put SearchTweets

Comment: now i will try with TwitterTest... of course i change it when i try with your answer

Comment: did you rebuild your jar then ?

Comment: man thnx. I recreate .jar from eclipse and all is ok. Now i want give some arguments from php on my jar. Is it possible? What i must change on my class and basic on shell_exec("java -jar ilias2.jar"); for give in jar arguments?

Comment: yes you certainly can `java -cp ilias.jar:lib/*.jar SearchTweets.Main arg1 arg2 arg3` you would retrieve those values in the `args` variable of main method